# The "metadata.json" file for the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' was not found

Tags: github, vagrant, virtual-machine

when i run vagrant up command i got the following error

$ vagrant up
The "metadata.json" file for the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' was not found.
Boxes require this file in order for Vagrant to determine the
provider it was made for. If you made the box, please add a
"metadata.json" file to it. If someone else made the box, please
notify the box creator that the box is corrupt. Documentation for
box file format can be found at the URL below:

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html

Answer (score 4):

I deleted dir .vagrant.d, then

```
vagrant box add <name>
```

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try `vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64` before `vagrant up`